# Efficiency of VBOs vs BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, webgl

I was curious what kind of performance improvement I should expect by using VBO's in three.js. I was under the impression that the recent Geometry rewrite that threejs did handled this already, but I could be wrong.

I'm trying to wrap my head around VBO's and am trying to gauge what to expect. I am working with Voxels, however I am hesitant to use Voxel.js since it seems to be dead and I also have an odd use case that I do not think will be supported well under it.

Overall I am trying to deepen my understanding of working with the GPU and any help on what performance improvements I should expect would be fantastic.

Comment: A BufferGeometry contains VBOs, that is to say, it contains a flat array of vertex data. Maybe you mean to compare BufferGeometry to a regular Geometry?

Comment: I thought BufferGeometry was just a friendly abstraction over VBOs?